# How to find optimal solution that maximizes summation of sinusoidals over amplitude and phase designers.

Tags: integration, optimization

We have a function:
$$
f(x,y,z) = x\cos{(\omega\:t+y+\phi_1)} + z\cos{(\omega\:t+y+\phi_2)}.
$$

I want to solve the following maximization problems:
$$
\max_{x,y,z} {\max_tf(x,y,z)}\qquad\text{or}\qquad\max_{x,y,z}\int_{<T>} f(x,y,z) dt.
$$

Surely, $x$ and $z$ are nonnegative, and $y$ is in $[0,2\pi)$.

Can someone give me hints for solving the problem, or let me know some references to solve this types of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem, the pointwise maximisation $$ \max_{x,y,z} \max_{t} f(x,y,z) $$ has not a solution: indeed, whatever $t$ and $y$ you select, the target function will diverge as $x$ and $z$ $\to \infty$, as the two cosine functions will return values bounded by $0$ and $1$, and their argument do not depend on $x,z$.

A similar line of thought is valid for the second problem too.Whatever candidate parameters $x,y,z$ you consider, you could increase the target function by increasing say $x$, which does not affect the period.

For the problem to be interesting, some constraint on $x,z$ might be considered.

In any case, both the problem are akin to maximising a function over three or four unknowns (as you can always solve the integral, for the second case): setting partial derivative to zero would be a good starting point. You woul find stationary points, and then you would have to check the stationary points corresponds to maxima.

Comment: @Danny_Kim, if anything is unclear I would be glad to expand upon it.

Comment: Thank you for a kind answer!